# Передача по инстанции или по инстанциям?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Как сказать правильно: *передача по инстанции* или *передача по инстанциям*?

Answer (score 3):

Инстанции соответствуют ступеням иерархии (в судебной системе, в прокуратуре). Поэтому *передать* в рамках одной системы можно *по инстанции выше* (если у заявителя появились для этого юридические основания, напр. отказ полученный в текущей инстанции) или *ниже* (если такое решение приняла вышестоящая инстанция). При этом дело или заявление, ***переданное по инстанции***, может ***ходить по инстанциям*** (пройти несколько таких инстанций). Но однократное действие передачи в таких системах происходит **по инстанции**. Видимо, в военной системе возможны ситуации, когда приказ, доклад об обстановке неизбежно проходит несколько ступеней иерархии, и там можно говорить о **передаче** (напр. приказа) **по инстанциям**.

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе русского языка нашлось только два примера, причем они разные:

> ― Это вы можете передать **по инстанции**, как Алекс ― Юстасу. [Марианна Баконина. Девять граммов пластита (2000)]
>
> ― Значит, так, ― передайте **по инстанциям**: если высадится танковая гвардейская Кантемировская дивизия… [Анатолий Гладилин. Большой беговой день (1976-1981)]

Я думаю, ответ зависит от того, какая передача подразумевается: "одноходовая" или "многоходовая".